# How to send many http request by sequentially in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I am creating a crawler using Node.js.

In the target web page, there are 10+ categories.

I can get them using my crawler.

And I make requests for each category. (10+ requests)

Then, each category page has 100+ items.

And I make requests for each item. (100+ requests)

So I need 10+ * 100+ requests!

My code is here.

```
const axios = require("axios")
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

async function request(url) {
    return await axios.get(url);
}

function main() {
    request(url).then(html => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);
        const categoryArray = $('table.table tbody').children('tr').toArray()

        categoryArray.map(category => {
            console.log("category: " + category.name)

            request(category.url).then( html => {
                const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);
                const items = $('table.table tbody').children('tr').toArray()

                console.log("item.length: " + items.length)

                items.map(item => {
                    request(item).then(html => {
                        const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);
                        const itemDetails = $('table.table tbody').children('tr').toArray()

                        console.log("item.name: " + itemDetails.name)
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

But it doesn't work...

The console.log looks like:

```
category: A
category: B
category: C
category: D
category: E
category: F
category: G
category: H
category: I
category: J
category: K
category: L
category: M
category: N
item.length: 0
item.length: 100
item.length: 100
item.length: 0
item.length: 100
item.length: 0
item.length: 0
item.length: 100
item.length: 0
item.length: 0
item.length: 0
item.length: 0
item.length: 0
item.length: 0
item.name: item1
(node:5409) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:5409) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

At the first time, it looks like working fine, but after some seconds, doesn't work.

I think that "categoryArray.map" doesn't wait for children's requests.

So the HTTP connection thread number is up to maximum.

I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: either look into async or use a queue (when a call is done, pop the next one off the array and repeat)

Comment: How does it not work? Are you getting an error? What is it? Are network calls being made at all? Please elaborate on the problem you're facing.

Comment: What about it doesn't work?  Please elaborate.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? What is a code for the `request()` function?

Comment: look into Promise.all

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `map` to begin with since you don't use its return value.  Consider the difference between `map` and `forEach`.  That isn't the core issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `Array.prototype.map` is not `Promise`-aware, so it can't wait for your requests.

Instead of using `map`, simply use `async`/`await` and iterate arrays using `for ... of`:

```
async function main() {
    const categoryArray = await request(categoryUrl)
    for (const category of categoryArray) {
        console.log("category: " + category.name)

        const items = await request(category.url)
        console.log("item.length: " + items.length)

        for (const item of items) {
            const itemDetails = await request(item)
            console.log("item.name: " + itemDetails.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed the code and it looks like working sequentially. But I have another problem... I edited my question, could you help me again please?

Comment: @yoonhok As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with your updated answer, at least in respect to this code. Seems simply that the result of your requests is giving an empty array, look there.